# the correct way to define web api post method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a .NET Web Api REST server which has a controller for the class customer which has a post method like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer()
{
    //getting the data in the request body****
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

and this is my class:

```
 class Customer
{
    public Customer(string name, string tell, string pass, string add)
    {
        FnameLname = name;
        Address = add;
        Password = pass;
        AccountNumber = tell;
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string FnameLname { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a C# form application consumer which i'm using RESTSharp to do so.
i'm trying to do a post request to create a Customer but i had no luck setting it up.
this is what i have got so far:

```
{
      Customer newc=new Customer(...); 
      var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.137.1:9090/");
      var request = new RestRequest("api/Customer",Method.POST);
      request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
      request.AddObject(newc);
      var response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

but it doesn't work.
i don't know if my controller method is wrong or the request is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Post method needs to take in a `Customer` parameter so that the WebAPI will try to bind the JSON in the request body to the `customer` parameter

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer)
{ ... }
```

Comment: i did this but it doesn't trigger